# refactoring function to have a robust design

Tags: python, refactoring

i am having a simple app example here:

say i have this piece of code which handles requests from user to get a list of books stored in a database.

```
from .handlers import all_books

@apps.route('/show/all', methods=['GET'])
@jwt_required
def show_books():
    user_name = get_jwt_identity()['user_name']
    all_books(user_name=user_name)
```

and in `handlers.py` i have :

```
def all_books(user_name):
        db = get_db('books')
        books = []
        for book in db.books.find():
            books.append(book)
        return books
```

but while writing unit tests i realised if i use `get_db()` inside `all_books()` it would be harder to unit test the method.
so i thought this would be the good way.

```
from .handlers import all_books

@apps.route('/show/all', methods=['GET'])
@jwt_required
def show_books():
    user_name = get_jwt_identity()['user_name']
    db = get_db('books')
    collection = db.books
    all_books(collection=collection)

def all_books(collection):
        books = []
        for book in collection.find():
            books.append(book)
        return books
```

i want to know what is the good design to use?
have all code doing one thing at one place like the first example or the second example is good.

To me first one seems more clear as it has all related logic at one place. but its easier to pass a fake collection in second case to unit test it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should probably use the mock library  see: https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#quick-guide

(if you use python2 you will need `pip install mock`)

```
def test_it():
    from unittest.mock import Mock,patch
    with patch.object(get_db,'function',Mock(return_value=Mock(books=[1,2,3]))) as mocked_db:
         x = get_db("ASDASD")
         console.log(x.books) 
         # you can also do cool stuff like this
         assert mocked_db.calledwith("ASDASD")
```

of coarse for yours you will have to construct a slightly more complex object

```
my_mocked_get_db = Mock(return_value=Mock(books=Mock(find=[1,2,3,4])))
with patch.object(get_db,'function',my_mocked_get_db) as mocked_db:
         x = get_db("ASDASD")
         print(x.books.find())
```

Comment: im making no calls to your judgement, there may be other reasons not to do get_db inside the function ... but unit tests isnt really a great one (decoupling of code might be... i cannot say for sure)

Comment: in your second code , `find` is something like a variable but its being used as a callable in the code below. is this specific to the `Mock` ?